# GWT Editor Validation HasEditorErrors is always empty

Tags: validation, gwt

I am using the GWT Editor and javax validation.

I have a model bean with a child bean like so ->

```
public interface BeanA {

    @Valid
    BeanB getBeanB();

    void setBeanB(BeanB b);
}

public interface BeanB {

    @NotEmpty
    public String getValue();

    public void setValue(String value);

}
```

There is a Widget that implements the LeafValueEditor, HasEditorErrors interfaces.

The value seems to be binding with no issue.

```
    public class MyWidget extends Composite implements 
                                 LeafValueEditor<String>, HasEditorErrors<String>{
    ...

    @Override
    public void showErrors(List<EditorError> errors) {
           // Even though the error is flagged 
           // the errors collection does not contain it.    
           }
}
```

When I call validate and the widget getValue returns null, the ConstraintViolation collection contains the error but when showErrors is called, the List is empty.

Any idea why the violation is found but then does not make it to the widget showErrors?

Comment: I am running into the same problem. Have you been able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a GWT 2.4 issue. I did the same example in GWT 2.5 and the path was correctly set and the error collection was correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GWT Editor, you would have `SimpleBeanEditorDriver` interface created by GWT.create(...). this interface has a method `setConstraintViolations(violations)` which gets your constraint violation from you. when you validate your Model, you would have `Set<ConstraintViolation<E>>` as violations, then you would pass this to your editor driver. for example

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<E>> violations = getValidator().validate(model,
            groups);
getEditorDriver().setConstraintViolations(violations)
```

After this, you would get widget-specific errors on the widget's `showErrors(List<EditorError> errors)` method.

Comment: I have all this. The violations contain the error, but showErrors collection is empty. Also, in the example  beanA shows errors fine but the nested beanB seems to be the issue.

Comment: Some more digging and the issue seems to be path resolution. The path to the property is beanB.value but the absolute path in simpleViolations.pushViolations is beanB.beanB.value.

Comment: Sorry! I haven't used inner binding... can't help you there :(